# Is my mosfet burned out?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics

Im using a fca47n60 mosfet and when I put my voltmeter on  the source and the collector, my voltmeter says that the two pins conduct electricity. What is wrong?

Comment: "drain", not collector.

Comment: Is the gate pin floating?

Answer (score 2):

Well, either you are measuring the body diode, have a short somewhere else, the MOSFET is turned on with Vgs > Vt, or the MOSFET is failed short.  If you have removed the MOSFET from the circuit and you are not measuring the body diode, then it is failed short and you need to replace it.  And I presume you mean source and drain as 'collector' is for a BJT.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that I might have hooked up the mosfet the wrong way! Oh no. Oh well thanks-I guess ill have to get a new one:(